# Error al declarar una variable con un tipo de dato en typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tengo el siguiente problema, quiero declarar una variable con un tipo de dato en específico.

Ejemplo:

```
 let nombre:string;
```

Al declarar esta, por consola muestra el siguiente el error

> "SyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters ".

Solo funciona si declaro al variable de esta forma:

```
 let nombre
```

Les dejo una imagen del error, si alguien sabe algo o ya se ha topado antes con el error, por favor comenten como lo resolvieron.

[image: Pantallazo del Error]

Comment: Por favor agrega tu código para poder ayudarte, solo una imagen no basta

Comment: Que tal Juan. Bienvenido a Stackoverflow!... Bien que nos hayas mostrado el error, pero también es necesario ver el código más allá de que solo hagas mención de tu declaración. La forma de declarar es la correcta, así que asumimos que el problema puede ser en otro lado... Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código correspondiente...

Comment: Aparte a tu pregunta, por favor date una vuelta por [ask] y así aumentar la calidad de tu pregunta... También podes hacer el [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio...

Comment: Desde javascript NO puedes declarar en typescript, pero desde typescript si puedes declarar javascript, haciendo un paso intermedio.

Answer (score 1):

Todavía no me queda claro si estas utilizando javascript o typescript, dado tu ejemplo asumo que es este último.

**Typescript** es un **superset se Javascript**, esto quiere decir que es un lenguaje que está construído encima del propio Javascript, en el sentido que agrega **nuevas características** al lenguaje, ofreciendo funcionalidades para nosotros, los programadores, que javascript no posee.

Entre estas nuevas posibilidades se encuentra la de poder declarar **tipos de datos** en nuestras variables, aportandole el tipado de datos a javascript.

En tu ejemplo la declaracion `let nombre: string;` es correcta, lo que podría seguir con una asignación como por ejemplo:

```
let a: string;
a = 'hola';
console.log(a);
```

o declarar y asignar al mismo tiempo:

```
let a: string = 'hola'
console.log(a);
```

Estos ejemplos no producen ningun tipo de error, aqui te adjunto la web de TS donde puedes testearlo online https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Si el ejemplo anterior quieres llevarlo a cabo en Javascript, te dara error ya que por un lado no existe la nomenclatura  `let [nombre_variable]:[tipo_dato];`  porque Js no soporta tipado de datos.